# Encode the polyline of latitude and longitude to ascii value

Tags: java, google-maps, polyline, google-polyline

anyone can have code to encode the polyline(array of ) latitude and longitude value to the ascii string in java

for e.g.

my array was in java

```
latlng{
  {22296401,70797251},
  {22296401,70797451},
  {22296401,70797851}
}
```

this above value store into the List object as GeoPoint type like

```
List<GeoPoint> polyline
```

and want to convert into ascii string like this

```
a~l~Fjk~uOwHJy@P
```

I need method which accept array of latlng value and return the ascii string
any help will be appreciate thanks in advance

Comment: What is the algorithm to get from a lat/long pair of numbers to that ASCII string?

Comment: this link is for decode the ascii string to the polyline array of latlng value http://www.geekyblogger.com/2010/12/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps.html

Comment: Note that that article contains a [link to a page](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm.html) that explains how to do the encoding. Now you just have to implement that...

Comment: i have seen that but not able to implement it, it's hard for me that why i asked the question here

Comment: Then please explain in detail what you have tried and where you get stuck. People don't like "please write this code for me" questions here...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/c85319eb7fd930dc?pli=1)

this two function was needed to encode the polyline array into the ascii string

```
private static String encodeSignedNumber(int num) {
    int sgn_num = num << 1;
    if (num < 0) {
        sgn_num = ~(sgn_num);
    }
    return(encodeNumber(sgn_num));
}

private static String encodeNumber(int num) {

    StringBuffer encodeString = new StringBuffer();

    while (num >= 0x20) {
        encodeString.append((char)((0x20 | (num & 0x1f)) + 63));
        num >>= 5;
    }

    encodeString.append((char)(num + 63));

    return encodeString.toString();

}
```

for testing try the co-ordinate from [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm.html) site and compare the output

here is the snippet

```
StringBuffer encodeString = new StringBuffer();
                    
String encode = Geo_Class.encodeSignedNumber(3850000)+""+Geo_Class.encodeSignedNumber(-12020000);                       
encodeString.append(encode);
encode = Geo_Class.encodeSignedNumber(220000)+""+Geo_Class.encodeSignedNumber(-75000);                      
encodeString.append(encode);
encode = Geo_Class.encodeSignedNumber(255200)+""+Geo_Class.encodeSignedNumber(-550300);                     
encodeString.append(encode);
                    
Log.v("encode string", encodeString.toString());
```

from the co-ordinate link you getting this point

```
Points: (38.5, -120.2), (40.7, -120.95), (43.252, -126.453)
```

ok so now you think the co-ordinate are why different see when you get new co-ordinate then you have subtract from the previous one for example

```
1. 3850000,-12020000 => 3850000,-12020000
2. 4070000,-12095000 => (4070000 - 3850000),(-12095000 - -12020000) => +220000, -75000
```

that value you have to pass to the encodeSignedNumber() method and you get the ascii value for that co-ordinate

and so on....