# Need to Incorporate Google Maps and a few of its services in my app

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an app and it requires to be able to show my location, display a route between two points I select, display nearby places like restaurants and cafes etc. and also should let me check-in at any place I want. To put it more simply, I need a smaller version of Google maps for my android app which would incorporate the Maps, Local, Check-in and Navigation abilities in there.

I have searched a lot and found almost nothing useful that would tell me whether I can be able to do these things or not? I just want a smaller version of Google Maps(including the Local, Navigation and Check-in functionalities) with the same layouts and graphics etc. to be present in my app. Is it possible? If yes, then could anybody please help me out?

Comment: hi check out this links http://stackoverflow.com/q/6140433/760489, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7266589/760489, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7228379/760489

Comment: not helpful at all. I have to tell I'm quite new here with a very limited concept of android etc.

Comment: I've somehow learnt that the Google Maps isn't Open Source. Meaning I wont't be able to get the above functionalities for my App. Is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have previous found this to be quite useful.
http://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/

However, please be aware that google has recently upgraded their android map api and I am not sure if they updated this app to match.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do several things.

Firstly, to incorporate Google Maps, your complete reference is available [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).

In simple steps:

1 Follow the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api): this will help add a simple google maps to your screen.

2 To be able to get your own location you will need to use the LocationListener and LocationManager in android. To do this, first **implement** the LocationListener in your activity.

`public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener`

3 Then you need to instantiate a few settings in your onCreate() method

```
     @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
      System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
      onLocationChanged(location);
    } 
  }
```

4 You need to be able to request for regular location updates. Include this in your onResume() method.

```
@Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
  }
```

5 If the app falls into the pause cycle, these updates shouldn't need to come.

```
@Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
  }
```

6 Your location listener implementation from step 2 requires that you have an onLocationChanged listener, implement it:

```
@Override   
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
}
```

7 Add these two methods to be notified of the provider of your location setting - the GPS or the Network.

```
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

8 Now we need to link this up to your google maps. I will show you one example of using the google maps API to be able to generate a market to show your current location. The other usages can be inferred from the API.

First create private fields in your code:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
Marker m;
```

9 Add these in your onCreate method - this instantiates your default marker position as 0,0 latitude and longitude.

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                .title("Position"));
```

10 In your onLocationChanged method, we need to refresh this marker as location changes. So add:

```
m.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));
m.setTitle("Your Position");

// Move the camera instantly to marker with a zoom
// of 15.
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 15));
```

This will be a simple way of updating the marker with your position, and should be a good intro to your Google Maps and location API in android.

Comment: I'll surely give it a read and get back to you in a while .. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually on your android activity  you will have "public class LocationActivity extends Activity" on top (replace LocationActivity with the name of your activity - probably MainActivity). You need to add the line "implements LocationListener" after it

Comment: but i heard implements MapActivity should be used

Comment: I have used it the exact way I have described and it works perfectly. Do try it

Comment: private GoogleMap mMap;
Marker m;

where do u put the above code ?

Comment: Im having problems with step 8 and step 9. please explain.

Comment: You put the private fields code right under the line 'public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener' and before any methods (like onCreate). Step 9 is just additional lines in your 'onCreate' method that you created earlier

Comment: Then its probably because you haven't followed the steps to incorporate google maps to your app correctly. Please follow the link carefully - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api